# Find the series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$ in powers of $z + 3i$? Then what is the region of convergence of this series?

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}$ in powers of $z + 3i$? Then what is the region of convergence of this series?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. This is my first time asking a question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1/(1-z)=1/(1+3i-(z+3i))=1/(1+3i)1/(1-(z+3i)/(1+3i))=1/(1+3i)\sum((z+3i)/(1+3i))^n$.

The region of convergence is $|z+3i|\lt\sqrt{10}$.

Now differentiate, term by term, twice.

So, $1/(1-z)^3=1/2\sum n(n+1)((z+3i)/(1+3i))^{n-1}$.